# Have one array reference two or more

Tags: javascript

So I want to know if it's possible to create a scenario like this in javascript:

Lets say I have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

And then I would like to create an array c that references the two arrays:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However when I change an element in one of the two arrays I would also like to have it automatically affect array c:

```
a[1] = 1
c = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Is there a way to make this possible in javascript?

Comment: Not directly by reference but you can write a function which combines and sorts both arrays. But this will das only be possible with read operations.

Comment: what should happen, if you splice `c` and add an item? should it got to the end of `a` or to the beginning of `b`?

Comment: JavaScript is always pass-by-value; everything is of value type.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if your question has been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional pass-by-reference approach doesn't exist in JavaScript, so you'll have to use a workaround. The simplest way would be to return `c` dynamically as a combination of `a` and `b` using a function. Another would be using an object and getter/setters to manipulate what you get when accessing `c`.

**Example:**

```js
var $ = (function () {
  /* Hidden arrays */
  var a = [1, 2, 3];
  var b = [4, 5, 6];

  /* Visible object. */
  return {
    get a () {
      return a;
    },
    set a (v) {
      a = v;
    },
    get b () {
      return b;
    },
    set b (v) {
      b = v;
    },
    get c () {
      return a.concat(b);
    },
  };
})();

/* Example */
console.log(JSON.stringify($.a), JSON.stringify($.b), JSON.stringify($.c));
$.a = [0, 1, 2];
console.log(JSON.stringify($.a), JSON.stringify($.b), JSON.stringify($.c));
$.b[1] = 7;
console.log(JSON.stringify($.a), JSON.stringify($.b), JSON.stringify($.c));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Proxy.

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = [4,5,6];
const c = new Proxy([a,b], {
    _localIndex: function(arrays, index) {
        index = +index;
        if( isNaN(index)) throw new TypeError("Expected numeric index");
        if( Math.floor(index) !== index) throw new RangeError("Index must be an integer");
        if( index < 0) throw new RangeError("Index must be positive");
        for( let i=0; i<arrays.length; i++) {
            if( arrays[i].length > index) return [i,index];
            index -= arrays[i].length;
        }
        throw new RangeError("Index out of bounds");
    },
    get: function(arrays, index) {
        if( index === "length") {
            return arrays.reduce((a,c)=>a+c.length,0);
        }
        if( index === "source") {
            return arrays;
        }
        const [arr, idx] = this._localIndex(arrays, index);
        return arrays[arr][idx];
    },
    set: function(arrays, index, value) {
        const [arr, idx] = this._localIndex(arrays, index);
        arrays[arr][idx] = value;
    }
});

console.log("Get c[4]: "+c[4]);
c[2] = 9;
console.log("Updated c[2], a is now: "+JSON.stringify(a));
console.log("Get c's source array: "+JSON.stringify(c.source));
a.push('x');
console.log("Pushed value to a, c is now: "+JSON.stringify(c.source));
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: nice way + info IE doesn't support this.